# Firebase Admin SDK - Missing or insufficient permissions - Emulator

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, nestjs, firebase-admin

I have a nestJS api calling the Firestore emulator, which in my local environment is returning the following error:

> Error 7 PERMISSION_DENIED: Missing or insufficient permissions.

When trying to access firestore.

I have checked the following:

- My firebase app is properly initialised
- The service account is available and properly imported
- The FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST environment variable is defined and points to the right host:port

The init code:

```js
import * as serviceAccount from './key.json';
import { initializeApp, cert, getApps } from 'firebase-admin/app';
// more imports

console.log({ serviceAccount }); // <= returns the json

@Module({})
export class FirebaseModule {
  static forRoot(): DynamicModule {
 

        const app = initializeApp({
          credential: cert(serviceAccount as ServiceAccount),
          databaseURL: 'https://xxxxxxx.firebaseio.com',
          projectId: 'xxxxxx',
        });

    // more init code

    console.log({app})  // <= returns the app object

  }
}
```

In Nest I have a guard that checks the access token sent by the client using the `getIdTokenResult()`, and this does not yield any error, which tells me that the app is indeed properly initialised and configured since it can interact with the auth emulator.

This service account and the integration with firestore have once worked and the issue I am dealing with is a regression, but it is unclear when / how it started.

Running `firebase-admin@11.8.0` fwiw.

Comment: do you have a firestore.rules file? If so, what does it contain? What does your firebase.json look like?